# What is cutting off bottom of text in Microsoft Word table?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2016

The bottom half of every word in the first column is blanked out:
[image]

I've already tried changing cell margins and paragraph line spacing as suggested by previous questions on superuser.

I thought I was experienced at Microsoft Word, so I'm frustrated I can't work out what I've done wrong to cause this to happen.

Here's a link to download the docx file if you want:
http://atomking.com/Cursed-Table.docx

Comment: Alternate URL if above link doesn't work: https://mega.nz/file/1JZg2R4L#_igLaLZMEsfhsA2DKl1Q66dpctr1jLvhHO3AbJ18dHQv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The table style you are using is causing the problem.
Changing or clearing the style solves the issue.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer.